# Find words start with specific word in regex

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

I am trying to find word with New keyword. Below is my code.

```
        string contents = " holla holla testing is for NewFinancial History:\"xyz\"  dsd  NewFinancial History:\"abc\"  New Investment History:\"abc\"  dsds  ";

        var keys = Regex.Matches(contents, @"New(.+?):", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace).OfType<Match>().Select(m => m.Groups[0].Value.Trim().Replace(":", "")).Distinct().ToArray();
```

In above Code it searches both NewFinancial History:\"xyz\" and New Investment History:\"abc\".
It should only find NewFinancial History:\"xyz\" not New Investment History:\"abc\". 
I want to find the word without space after New keyword. The above code searches both with and without space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
\bNew(\S.+?):
```

to match `New` followed by a non-space

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bM9oS9/1)

Or else:

```
\bNew\B(.+?):
```

to match `New` followed by a non-word-boundary